# Can I skip the initial settings screen when launching Space Pirates and Zombies?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

Playing the Steam version of the game, I find that every time I launch the game a launcher with settings and options for the game will pop up first. While useful for the first few launches, I find the default settings are adequate and have no need for this settings screen every time I launch the game. Is there any way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Developer's say no](http://www.spacepiratesandzombies.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=2362&p=17095) I'm afraid...

And I guess I can see why.